# Yandex SmartCaptcha не работает в Laravel + VUE

Tags: laravel, vue.js, captcha

Проект на Laravel + VUE. Контактная форма написана на HTML, подключена в неё Yandex SmartCaptcha. Капча отображается, но при нажатии на галку "Я не робот" получаю бесконечную обработку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если подключение VUE из проекта удалить, то всё ок.

Что может быть не так?

Comment: Проверяйте что пишется в консоли браузера и логах сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что VUE подключался ко всему DOM. Из-за этого возникал конфликт. Теперь подключают VUE только к тем блокам, к которым он относится. А форма не относился к ней. Поэтому стало всё ок.